# C# Get Network Adapter information from a given adapter

Tags: c#, network-programming

I need to get the IP Address, Subnet mask, gateway, DNS and check if DHCP is enabled from a given adapter.
I have this code that loads my Ethernet and Wireless Adapters:

```
   public void LoadAdapters()
    {            
        if (cmb1_adaptadores.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
            {
                var ipProps = adapter.GetIPProperties();
                IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();                    
                if (adapter.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 || adapter.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                {
                    cmb1_adaptadores.Items.Add(adapter.Description);
                }
            }
        }
        cmb1_adaptadores.SelectedIndex = 0; 
    }
```

I've found many sample codes with foreach and loops to get every adapter ip, dns, etc.
I need an easier thing, but I don’t know how to approach it.

Using the adapter’s description from my combobox, I want to fill some labels with the adapters info, I mean:

```
If (adapter.description == cmb1_adaptadores.SelectedItem)
{
labelIP1 = adapter...
labelGATEWAY1 = adapter...
}
```

Of course it will be more complicated than a simple if, but this way every time a new item is selected, this method will run using the description selected in the combobox to reference the adapter.

Comment: ...and you have trouble with...what?

Comment: Getting the adapters information IP, DNS, etc. and making the relation between adapter's description and adapter's network info. I know it seems simple but I've searched a lot and don't get it.